# Postgresql regular expression with semi colon

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to use regular expression to split String values from a field.
Here is something to follow my question

```
mydatabase=> SELECT regexp_replace('a1=1,2;B2b=2,3,4;C3c={3,4,5;4,5,6};D4d={4,5,6;7,8,9}', 
                                   '([^0-9]|^)([=.*])(?=;|$)', '\1 \2', 'g');

   regexp_replace                    
------------------------------------------------------
 a1=1,2;B2b=2,3,4;C3c={3,4,5;4,5,6};D4d={4,5,6;7,8,9}
(1 row)
```

But I want the result like below

```
mydatabase=>YOUR_ANSER_QUERY

regexp_replace
------------------
a1=1
B2b=2,3,4
C3c={3,4,5;4,5,6}
D4d={4,5,6;7,8,9}
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have semi-colon within your brackets. to escape them, i have added `(?![0-9]) a negative look-ahead so specified pattern not exist.` to separate them into table

This should do it:

```
SELECT  regexp_split_to_table( 'a1=1,2;B2b=2,3,4;C3c={3,4,5;4,5,6};D4d={4,5,6;7,8,9}', ',?[1-2]?(;(?![0-9]))');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used online regex replace verifier at http://regexr.com

The regex to search for is `([^=]+)=(\{[^\}]+\}|[^;]+)(?:;|$)`
and the regex to replace is `$1=$2\r`.

For your input string they give the required result.

Note that this verifier requires `$` sign (+ number) to refer to a capturing group.